# @DocDescendants and @DocChildren are special text

Tags: lotus-formula

I got an error when I used this operation (Incorrect data type). I want to get the average of the below formula. What is the correct formula to get the average of @DocDescendants and @DocChildren? OR is there any alternative way to count the category and sub category then get the avg for each category?

avg:=@DocDescendants/@DocChildren;

OR this also

avg:=@Text(@DocDescendants/@DocChildren);

OR this also

avg:=@ToNumber(@DocDescendants)/ @ToNumber(@DocChildren);

Answer (score 1):

@DocDescendants("%") will return with actual number of decendant documents and @DocChildren("%") will return number of child records, if you omit the "%" then return value is unusable 'special text', there are other optional parameters which are well documented in domino designer help.

note: "%" returns a string so to compute average you'll need to wrap the value in @textToNumber, You might also need to wrap the calculation in @Error to handle docs with no responses which will mean your attempting a division by zero. This might all seem complicated, and another reason to grumble at Lotus but Formula language once you get your head around it is blindingly fast and very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried that, but just looked it up in the help and it says *"You cannot convert special text to a number."* I guess that's what's special about it :) Must be something about the inner workings of the view indexing...
Anyway, knowing about the limitations of other formulas in the views, the only think I can think of is running an agent that goes through the entries in the view and for document entries uses the `NotesViewEntry.DescendantCount` and `NotesViewEntry.ChildCount` to calculate the value and save it in the document. It could be a scheduled agent (sighed with an ID that has access to edit the documents).

Does that help?

Comment: @Hristo- this will be using in the view. I have a category let us say Submission, then a sub category Project.For each project there is 1 or more Submission request No. For example I have 4 projects in Submission 1. for the First project I have a 1 Submission Request, for the second I have 4, for the third project I have 5 and for the 4th project I have 6. Sum all the Submission request No divided 4 projects that is the average of Submission 1 category.

Comment: I dont want to use the "Average per sub -category" because I want to show the result in the category and the subcategory should not show the average fot each project.

Comment: Is this possible using Formula?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this calculation with a formula. There probably isn't. I would resort to using LotusScript to do the calculations on the fly and display the results in some form. Or, as I suggested in my answer (and if that's feasible), store each result in the respective document in a field that you use in the view.

Comment: @Hristo- Ok. If I used Lotuscript is this possible to update the view category name concatenated with the average(eg. Submission 1 (6-this is the average of DocChild and Docdescendant))?

Comment: If I understand your example correctly, this sounds like something that would work. However, before coding this, you might want to first test which document you need to update and how will this be displayed in the view. Maybe try typing the `category` text in the document, just to make sure the view will look the way you want.